# Intercept the 'Expression' property of IQueryable Provider and gets its e-sql

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, entity-framework-4, xml-serialization

Normally I can query an entity context using linq in the typical way,

```
IQueryable<Product> query = from p in db.Products
                            where p.ProductID > 1
                            select query;
```

Now say I wanted to get the expression of this IQueryable, serialize it, and pass it over the wire to be reconstructed on the other end,

```
Expression ex = query.Expression;

XElement xExpression = serializer.Serialize(ex); 

wcfClient.InvokeSomeServiceMethod(xExpression);
```

How would I reconstruct this on the other end? (the server end, to be specific)

I need to create a new instance of IQueryable and 'set' the expression used by the underlying provider by actually passing in an Expression instance, is this possible? There is no setter on IQueryable by default, of course. More specifically I just need an ObjectQuery so I can call ToTraceString() and get the entity sql on the other end. I cant seem to find any point where I can inject the Expression directly.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your question is: How can I pass and invoke the query inside the server?

Comment: Yes, essentially. I need to pass in an Expression instance though, because the query is written on the client, not the server.

Comment: It is not easy. Look for example how OData is doing this (passess query over the wire and reconstructs it on the server side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you look at [InterLINQ](http://interlinq.codeplex.com/). It provides the ability to serialize an expression and transmit over WCF.

I'm using it with NHibernate to achieve a similar outcome to what you're describing and it seems to work well. (There's a bit to get your head around though, so as others have suggested, WCF Data Services / OData would be be quicker/easier).

Answer (score 2):

Really, you have two options.

1. Don't pass general queries over the wire. The server should have a `GetProductsWithProductIdGreaterThan` method that the client invokes.
2. Look at [WCF Data Services](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdata%2Fbb931106&ei=pql7TsjYJeaEsgK0zaCyAw&usg=AFQjCNExvmsZBH2zHEFpxK4PGHzpN5gAPw).

The third option, the one your requesting, is just hard.= Even if you're extremely fluent in LINQ, WCF, and `Expression`, it's still extremely difficult.

Comment: I think the first option is the simplest one, but it not dynamic as the rest

Comment: +1 WCF Data Services with OData are exactly for this scenarios otherwise you are going to write your own [IQueryable provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) to handle server side and client side - btw. expression trees are not serializable so you must also make your own serialization process to pass them from server to client.